# What did Rost mean by "I spoke to no-one"?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

> Aloy: Opening a gate for an outcast?
>
> Rost: Some who are shunned reaped honor before disgrace.
>
> Aloy: So much for tribal law.
>
> Rost: **I spoke to no one.** And now we must both keep silent for we are outside the Embrace. These are the true wilds, Aloy, with threats unlike any you have ever faced.

What does Rost mean by "I spoke to no one"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The outcasts are forbidden from speaking to the rest of the Nora and other outcasts, so he literally means that. He technically obeyed the prohibition on speaking while still having some degree of interaction, due to the respect some in the tribe still gave him.